# Use CampaignMember.Id in List Mail

Tags: email, email-template

I need to send an email to all CampaignMembers. I need to include (among other things) the Id of the receiving CampaignMember in the email text.

It's basically a custom link that points to a public visualforce page and the CampaignMember Id is sort of the "password".

However, when I add `{{{CampaignMember.Id}}}` to my mail text, it's blank for all recipients!

Steps to reproduce:

1. -> Campaigns
2. -> selecting a specific campaign
3. -> Send list Email
4. -> type text below

Here is my email body:

```
Hi there,

please use the link below to register for our company event:

https://oursalesforcedomain.force.com/companyevent/?id={!CampaignMember.Id}

​Thanks
```

From my understanding, all I have to do is use the placeholder for the CampaignMember.Id. However, it always returns blank hence the invitation link is not working.

What do I need to differently?

Comment: Can you add like more info or code which is part of email template?

Comment: Hi Santanu, thanks for your comment. I updated the original post with more info, steps to reproduce and the specific email body. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you create a separate field store this Id and refer that field in the link and check if that works for you